# How to combine Futures of different types into a single Future without using zip()

Tags: scala, akka, future, applicative

I want to create a Future of type `Future[(Class1,Class2,Class3)]` from below code. However the only way I have found to do this is by using zip(). I find the solution ugly and properly not optimal. Can anybody enlightened me.

```
val v = for (
    a <- {
        val f0:Future[Class1] = process1
        val f1:Future[Class2] = process2
        val f2:Future[Class3] = process3
        f0.zip(f1).zip(f2).map(x => (x._1._1,x._1._2,x._2))
    } yield a  // Future[(Class1,Class2,Class3)]
```

I have also tried to use `Future.sequence(List(f0, f1, f2))` but this will not work as the new Future will have type of `Future[List[U]]` where `U` is the lub of `Class1/2/3` whereas I want a 3-tuple preserving the original types

Comment: An aside to @oxbow_lakes' answer, here is a general intuition for applicatives: When you have a function `f` of type `(A, B, ...) => Z` and you want to _lift_ it to a function of type `(F[A], F[B], ...) => F[Z]`, you need applicative. In your case, `f = (_, _, _)` and `F = Future`.

Answer (score 51):

```
val result: Future[(Class1, Class2, Class3)] = for {
  _ <- Future.unit
  val f1 = process1
  val f2 = process2
  val f3 = process3
  v1 <- f1
  v2 <- f2
  v3 <- f3
} yield (v1, v2, v3)
```

Comment: Wouldn't this cause the computation to be executed sequentially versus in parallel?

Comment: No, if you'd put the processX calls inside the for-comprehension it would, since flatMap would be used. Since fX is a Future, it means that processX will start off the computation and return the Future immediately.

Comment: wow, genious! coming from OO background, I am so behind in functional programming and futures.. do you have any sort of cheatsheets for all those mappings? :)

Comment: @Zennichimaro I have described some of these patterns on my blog: http://viktorklang.com/blog/

Answer (score 35):

### Applicative Functors

What you are asking for is an applicative functor for a future. See scalaz **[Applicative](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Applicative.scala) Builder** pattern. It should be rather trivial to roll your own on the back of `zip`

```
(f0 |@| f1 |@| f2)(g) //g is function (Class1, Class2, Class3) => Z
```

This is equivalent to the direct applicative:

```
(f0 <***> (f1, f2))(g)
```

Scalaz ships with a *banana braces* method which forms a tuple from the target and the arguments (i.e. what you asked for). So your solution will be:

```
f0 <|**|> (f1, f2) //that. is. all.
```

You get all this simply by defining a typeclass instance for the following typeclass:

```
trait Apply[Z[_]] {
  def apply[A, B](f: Z[A => B], a: Z[A]): Z[B]
}
```

So for future this looks like:

```
implicit val FutureApply = new Apply[Future] {
  def apply[A, B](f: Future[A => B], a: Future[A]): Future[B] = 
    (f zip a) map { case (fn, a1) => fn(a1) }
  }
}
```

(Actually you'd need `Pure` and `Functor` as well. Might as well implement `Bind` whilst you're at it - see appendix)

The great thing about this pattern is that you will start to see it everywhere (e.g. in `Option`, in `Validation`, in `List` etc). For example, the cartesian product of 2 streams is:

```
s1 <|*|> s2
```

---

### Notes

*All the above assuming scalaz 6, doubtless scalaz 7 for 2.10 will ship with these typeclasses by default. `Pure` has been renamed `Pointed` in scalaz7.*

---

### Appendix

Other type class instances for future:

```
implicit val FuturePure = new Pure[Future] {
  def pure[A](a: =>A): Future[A] = Future { a }
}
implicit val FutureBind = new Bind[Future] {
  def bind[A, B](a: Future[A], f: A => Future[B]): Future[B] = a flatMap f
}
implicit val FutureFunctor = new Functor[Future] {
  def map[A, B](a: Future[A], f: A => B): Future[B] = a map f
}
```

Comment: oxbow_lakes I'm not sure to understand: isn't Scalaz supposed to enable the syntax by default? It only provides an Applicative builder but does not provide an already-built applicative for Future or other standard Scala types?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using akka look at dataflow: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.2/scala/dataflow.html

you need to use the Delimited Continuations plugin (but thats easy with sbt) then something like:

```
val f:Future[(Class1,Class2,Class3)] = flow {
  val f0 = process1
  val f1 = process2
  val f2 = process3
  (f0(), f1(), f2())
}
```

should compile.

in build.sbt:

```
autoCompilerPlugins := true

addCompilerPlugin("org.scala-lang.plugins" % "continuations" % "2.9.1")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use also cats:

```
import cats._
import cats.instances.future._
```

there are few useful ways of doing this:

First more universal option:

```
Applicative[Future].map3(f0, f1, f2){ 
  (f0r, f1r, f2r) => //do something with results
}
```

and simpler :) that'll just return tuple Future[(f0.type, f1.type, f2.type)

```
Applicative[Future].tuple3(f0, f1, f2)
```